# Formating tables

Tags: tables

I am trying to produce a table within the document however it isn't working as it just comes up with an error saying

> \hline -> \noalign

and I don't know what this means and all of the other tables within this document have the exact same layout and they work fine. My code is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Numerical Prefixes}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\hline
Number & Prefix\\
%heading
\hline
1 & Mono\\
2 & Di (bis)\\
3 & Tri (tris)\\
4 & etra (Tetrakis)\\
5 & Penta (pentakis)\\
6 & Hexa (hexakis)
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
```

I know this isn't the typical way to write code on here but I'm not sure how to lay it out in that way. Any help would be great.

Comment: `6 & Hexa (hexakis)` should actually be `6 & Hexa (hexakis)\\ ` If the table row has not been ended, you can not add a `\hline`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a '\\' at the end of `6 & Hexa (hexakis)`.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Numerical Prefixes}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\hline
Number & Prefix\\
%heading
\hline
1 & Mono\\
2 & Di (bis)\\
3 & Tri (tris)\\
4 & etra (Tetrakis)\\
5 & Penta (pentakis)\\
6 & Hexa (hexakis)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
```

Without really knowing, I think the broad overview of what happened was you are asking it to put a horizontal line through your "6 & Hexa (hexakis)" and it didn't like that.